# How to I write this output command to a file

Tags: linux, bash, tail, hexdump

I'm trying to get every new line with tail from a file and transform it to `hexdump`, but I'm unable to write it to a file, I've tried with `>>` and `| tee -a destfile` but it doesn't give any error but stops working.

So, I have a binary file (data.bin) that is always growing new lines with a script.I'm trying to read and transform it to hexadecimal, that works well, and it outputs well:

```
tail -f data.bin | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"'
```

this outputs this:

```
01 55 1d fa 14 ae b5 41 ec 51 3c 42 64 55 00 00
74 5e f7 5d 00 00 00 00 02 55 1d fa 33 33 b3 41
7b 14 3f 42 63 55 00 00 74 5e f7 5d 00 00 00 00
```

When I try to do this

```sh
tail -f data.bin | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"' >> destfile.txt
```

It creates an empty file and doesn't write anything.

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you used and its results (created an empty file, created no file, ...)? Usually `... >> file` should work.

Comment: @GonçaloSantos Please [edit] your question to add requested information instead of answering in a comment.

Comment: If you redirect the output of a command to a file, most programs will use fully buffered output instead of line-buffered output when `stdout` is connected to a terminal. If `tail -f` doesn't result in a sufficient amount of output you may have to wait long enough to see the output in the file.

Comment: @Bodo sry, I already edited. 

I'll try to wait longer

Comment: @Bodo It still running until now and it doesn't write anything to the file

Comment: The -f option of the tail command is intended to work in an interactive mode, maybe that's the problem. Try to skip the hexdump transformation, to check if the problem is in tail buffering the output in a non compatible way

Comment: @GonçaloSantos The default buffer size is 4096 bytes. One line of output seems to have 16*3 bytes, so you would need about 86 lines of output to get it actually written to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect the output of a command, the output stream becomes fully buffered, so it will not be visible until flushed. You could read for exaple [this link](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering) for more information.

To make the output line buffered you can use [`stdbuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) utility from GNU coreutils:

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f input | stdbuf -oL hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"' >> destfile.txt
```

That way the output will be flushed each line.

Comment: This worked!!! Omg thank you so much, hopefully I learn more bash from now on!